# Two absolute value equations with two unknowns. Possible to retrieve sign?

Tags: absolute-value

I have two equations:
$|c x_1 + d x_2 | = u $
and 
$|c x_2 - d x_1 | = v $.
I know c, d, v and u. Is it possible to find out if 
$c x_1 + d x_2$ and $c x_2 - d x_1$ is bigger than or smaller than $0$? I have tried googling and also to solve it with wolfram alpha, but I am stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't. $|c x_1 + d x_2 | = u \implies c x_1 + d x_2 = \pm u$ (and similarly for the $2nd$). Without further restrictions on $x_1$ and $x_2$, we can get valid solutions for $x_1$ and $x_2$ by choosing any one case from each of the $2$ sets of equations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be clear, I don't need to solve for x1 and x2. I am only interested in if u is positive or negative and the same for v. You are saying this is not possible?

Comment: Correct, that's not possible. As Ishan explained, any combinations of the signs  for $cx_1+dx_2$ and $cx_2-dx_1$ is possible generally. Of course, if $u=0$ or $v=0$ then the the sign of the respective term will always be zero.

Comment: Thanks so much! In my case, c = cos(theta/2) and d = sin(theta/2). I can change theta to my liking and evaluate on of the two (or both) equations again (but its costly). Given that I have the u and v from earlier, can I change theta to get enough information to retrieve the sign of u and v? If so, any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

The linear equation
$$\begin{eqnarray}
c x_1 + d x_2 = U \\
 - d x_1 +c x_2= V
\end{eqnarray}$$
has exactly one solution if and only if its determinant $c^2+d^2\neq 0$ . For real $c$ and $d$ this is equivalent to  $(c,d)\neq (0,0)$. It does not depend on $U$ and $V$. If $(c,d)\neq (0,0)$ then there is a solution for every $(U,V)\in\{(u,v),(u,-v),(-u,v),(-u,-v)\}$ .